# java md5 compiling error

Tags: java, java-me, md5

i just try to use MD5 library in java, but i got some errors,

when I try to compile it, I got this error :

```
digest(byte[],int,int) in java.security.MessageDigest cannot be applied to (byte[])
```

I try to compile it by wtk (j2me)
What is the problem ?. thanks

here is the code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MD5 {
    public static String getMD5(String input) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
            String hashtext = number.toString(16);
            // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
            while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
            }
            return hashtext;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        System.out.println(getMD5("Javarmi.com"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: sorry, I thought i already format it.

Comment: The code compiles without any issues on jdk 1.6.

Comment: @deddi can you please give us the version of your jdk?  "javac -version"

Comment: @RD  javac -version
javac 1.6.0_18

Comment: as john pointed out, it works fine on 1.6

Comment: is there any relation within wtk i use ?

Comment: Isn't j2me a cut-down version of the JDK?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use WTK, perhaps you have [this version of `MessageDigest`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/security/satsa-api/jsr177/java/security/MessageDigest.html), it doesn't have `digest(byte[])`. So, you need to write something like this:

```
int MD_SIZE = 16;
byte[] messageDigest = new byte[MD_SIZE];
byte[] message = ...;
md.update(message, 0, message.length);
md.digest(messageDigest, 0, MD_SIZE);
```

Also note that you use `String.getBytes()`, so your digest depends on the system default encoding. You need to use `String.getBytes(String encoding)` in order to get portable results.

Comment: I am trying to authenticate using md5 in nokia s40 series but not able to do so. The code is working with charm on samsung. Any help would be appreciated.